# Creating a professional changelog using an AlertDialog (on Android in Java)

Tags: java, android, html, android-alertdialog, changelog

I am new to the Android app development (in Java) and I am also new to stackoverflow, so this is my first post/question. :)
Anyway, what I want, is, to create a more or less professional changelog using an AlertDialog. I wanted to set the message of it unsing strings. Ok, this worked well. But then it looked like this:

```
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
```

But I want that it looks like this:

```
Text Text Text Text

Text Text

Text Text Text Text Text
```

For this I tried to add HTML tags to the string.xml file:`<string name="About"><html><head>Text Text Text</head><body><b><p>Text Text Text Text Text Text </p></b></body></html></string>`
(Just trying out what possibly could work)

And this worked for me only with bold-tags and stuff but I just couldn't figure out, how I can do it that my changelog looks like about the second example.

Can you help me, pls?

I'm looking forward to your suggestions!

PS: Sorry for the bad examples but I can't add images yet! :( and Sorry for my not so good English but I hope you could understand me! ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you try to do. What is the difference between your two examples? Just that text spans across multiple lines? Or there there some bold text too?

Comment: Yes, I actually meant the difference between the singel line and the multi line, but it is not bad. :) It was a bit difficult to explain my problem without any images. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `\n` in your String for a newline. Or use the paragraph tag, but I don't know if it is recognized. Like

```
<p>Texttext</p><p>second line</p>
```

Comment: WOW! That was fast! Anyway, I thank you for your answer, I tried the "\n" out and it worked great! So, I didn't know that it would be so easy!

Answer (score 0):

u can use HTML as source eg. on **.setText(String) / .append(String)** via:

```
String fromHtml = Html.fromHtml("<u>html code</u>"))
```

for new line use escape char **\n** or in html **< br />**